# How to query the result of "ss" command?

Tags: linux

I need to query the result of the `ss` command in Linux. The documentation says that there is an optional query parameter but I do not know how to use it. Where/how can I learn that?

More specifically, I need to get the IP addresses of connections that are connected to the port `442`

For example, when I run `sudo ss -tun` if I get this,

```
Netid  State  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port       Process
tcp    ESTAB  0       0       1.1.1.1:442           2.2.2.2:9999
tcp    ESTAB  0       0       1.1.1.1:22            3.3.3.3:9999
tcp    ESTAB  0       0       [::ffff:1.1.1.1]:55   [::ffff:4.4.4.4]:9999
tcp    ESTAB  0       0       [::ffff:1.1.1.1]:442  [::ffff:5.5.5.5]:9999
```

What I want is this,

```cs
2.2.2.2
5.5.5.5 // This could be [::ffff:5.5.5.5], it is fine.
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter by port 442, then pipe through `awk` to extract 4th column.

```
ss -o state established sport = :442 | awk '{print $4}'
```

It seems that filter syntax is not well documented on `ss` manpage, but you can find many tutorials and examples in Google.

Also check `awk` documentation to learn how to obtain the exact output that you want.